# Does Entity framework populate all records when we create entity collection object?

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework

I am developing an application where I am using Entity framework. In the form load method, I am creating object of the entity collection. Suppose, we have a `Northwind` database and EF model is named `NorthWindEntities`. So in my Form load method I am doing something like this

`using (NorthWindEntites nwdb = new NorthWindEntities)`

Now If I hover over the nwdb object or add this object to watch and do something like `nwdb.Customers`, I can see all the customer entities.

I want to know that If `nwdb model` is not yet populated with `Customer` records, then how come customer records are being shown using `nwdb.Customers` in add watch. Is it that when we created nwdb object of `NorthWindEntities`, it populated all the entites and queries are being executed on local nwdb object???

If yes then this is alarming as their can be millions of records.

Comment: [Deferred execution.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/)

Comment: I guess it might be lazy loading - virtual navigation properties are first populated when you access them. When you hover over a property in the debugger it populates your entities.

Comment: @MattBurland - You mean to say that query doesnt execute when the following code runs: 

'var query = from customer in db.Customers  

            where customer.City == “Paris” 

            select customer;'

But if you hover over 'query' object in VS, you can see the customer entities in it. Why they are visible if query object is empty at this point of time.?

Comment: @UsmanMalik: Because by hovering over them *you have forced it to populate*. They aren't there unless you look at them. That includes in the debugger. You will probably notice a slight delay before it opens. That's when it's grabbing the data.

Answer (score 0):

EF only queries your database when you actually try to do something with the data - e.g., assigning it `.ToArray()`.  When you inspect values, you force EF to query the database.  If you have Lazy Loading enabled, your behavior will be somewhat different.